# not getting the right value from my query in typeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm, typeorm

i want to get the discoveries of  my user table but i don't think i have got the right syntax, i have researched typeorm website but they didn't fetch a the lower entity in a many to one relation.

i have a table of users and their discoveries, but i want to get all the one discovery of a particular user. and also get all their discoveries in another query.

below is a function as a callback to a connected function for getting the discoveries

```
const fetchDiscovery = (DiscoveryObject, connection) => {
  let fetchedDiscovery;
  let DiscoveryRepository = connection.getRepository(DiscoverySchema);
  
    fetchDiscovery = await DiscoveryRepository.findOne({
      DiscoveryTitle: DiscoveryObject.DiscoveryTitle,
      userID: DiscoveryObject.userID,
    });
    const fetchDiscoveries = await DiscoveryRepository.find({userID: DiscoveryObject.userID,
    });
  console.log(
    "the Discovery has been fetched from the database",
    fetchDiscovery
  );
  return fetchDiscovery;
};
```

my problem here is how do i fetch the Discovery of a user. i have not find any idea to do this in all my time researching about the topic.

Comment: Please consider refactoring your question as it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve, maybe you can draw a small table that shows how you want your result to look when it's working. Also, in your code, I see variables that are not declared like `fetchResource`

Comment: done sir, pleasse help

Comment: i want get the actual discovery